# How to programmatically change Focus behaviour between CollectionView Cells on tvOS?

Tags: gridview, uicollectionview, focus, tvos

[image: Image displaying a GRID Collection View, having multiple channels with programs for each Channel]

I have designed a Grid Collection View for GUIDE/EPG.
The default focus behaviour on tvOS when we swipe down, is to focus to any cell which is available below, which is located at the middle of the focused Cell.

Such as, 
The focus is moving from S4 R3 to S5 R3 when I swipe down. 
But the expectation is to move from S4 R3 to S5 R2.

Similary, the expected focus movement from S3 R6 to S4 R5. But the default focus moves to S4 R6.

How to override the focus behaviour on tvOS, to provide unique focus when swiping across this Grid Collection View. 
Please see the attached image for reference.

Comment: Hi Senthil. Did you find a way to to this?

Comment: Nope, it works like that only. Couldn't find any solution for that.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend this Guid maybe help you . [Github](https://github.com/inspace-io/INSElectronicProgramGuideLayout)